# Where does this superfluous colon, at the end of my \subsubsection title, come from?

Tags: sectioning, ieeeconf

I can't understand the behavior of the code snippet below

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10 pt, conference]{ieeeconf}  
\begin{document}
\subsubsection{stiffness} %--> There is no colon here!
\end{document}
```

which generates

[image]

Where does the superfluous colon, at the end of my `\subsubsection` title, come from?

Here is the log file corresponding to the compilation above.

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (MiKTeX 2.9.6960 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2019.2.4)  17 SEP 2019 21:15
entering extended mode
**./root.tex
(root.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
(IEEEconf.cls

Document Class: IEEEconf 2009/04/05 v1.4 IEEE Computer Society 8.5x11" conference proceedings
\@IEEEtrantmpdimenA=\dimen102
\@IEEEtrantmpdimenB=\dimen103
\@IEEEtrantmpcountA=\count80
\@IEEEtrantmpcountB=\count81
\@IEEEtrantmptoksA=\toks14
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OT1+ptm on input line 794.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/psnfss\ot1ptm.fd"
File: ot1ptm.fd 2001/06/04 font definitions for OT1/ptm.
)
\@IEEEnormalsizefontbaselineskip=\skip41

-- This is a 10 point document.
\normalsizebaselineskip=\skip42
\normaljot=\skip43
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <5> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1113.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <5> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1113.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <7> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1113.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <7> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1113.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <8> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1113.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <8> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1113.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <9> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1113.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <9> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1113.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <10> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1113.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <10> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1113.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <11> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1113.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <11> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1113.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <12> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1113.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <12> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1113.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <16> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1113.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <16> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1113.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <20> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1113.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <20> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1113.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <24> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1113.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <24> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1113.

\IEEEilabelindentA=\dimen104
\IEEEilabelindentB=\dimen105
\IEEEilabelindent=\dimen106
\IEEEelabelindent=\dimen107
\IEEEdlabelindent=\dimen108
\labelindent=\dimen109
\IEEEiednormlabelsep=\dimen110
\IEEEiedmathlabelsep=\dimen111
\IEEEiedtopsep=\skip44
\c@section=\count82
\c@subsection=\count83
\c@subsubsection=\count84
\c@paragraph=\count85
\c@IEEEsubequation=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip45
\belowcaptionskip=\skip46
\c@figure=\count87
\c@table=\count88
\@IEEEeqnnumcols=\count89
\@IEEEeqncolcnt=\count90
\@IEEEtmpitemindent=\dimen112
\c@biography=\count91
\@IEEEtranrubishbin=\box27
) (root.aux)
\openout1 = `root.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.


** Conference Paper **
Before submitting the final camera ready copy, remember to:

 1. Manually equalize the lengths of two columns on the last page
 of your paper;

 2. Ensure that any PostScript and/or PDF output post-processing
 uses only Type 1 fonts and that every step in the generation
 process uses the US letter (8.5in X 11in) paper size.

[1

{C:/Users/.../AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}

]
(root.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 779 strings out of 492946
 13196 string characters out of 3135516
 71718 words of memory out of 3000000
 4758 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 25846 words of font info for 55 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 26i,4n,19p,254b,105s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
{C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/enc/dvips/base/8r.enc}<C:/Progra
m Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/urw/times/utmri8a.pfb>
Output written on root.pdf (1 page, 9150 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 11 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

*PS. 1* The output above is a pdfLaTeX's touch, yet XeLaTeX's result is also the same.

*PS. 2* I'm using MikTeX 2.9.6972 on a Windows-10 machine.

*PS. 3* One reproduces the same result by substituting `ieeeconf` with `IEEEconf` (Document Class: IEEEconf 2009/04/05 v1.4 IEEE Computer Society 8.5x11" conference proceedings).

Comment: texlive doesn't have an `ieeeconf.cls` it does have `IEEEconf.cls` but that does not have a `[conference]` option and produces no colon on your test file if I uppercase IEEE (and produces a warning about the unknown option) (it adds a full stop after the heading not a colon) It is an inline heading designed to be set as the start of the following paragraph.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I added a 3rd postscript stating that I get the same problematic output by even using `IEEEconf.cls` instead of `ieeeconf.cls`.

Comment: texlive has `Document Class: IEEEconf 2009/04/05 v1.4 IEEE Computer Society 8.5x11" conference proceedings`  which produces a full stop not a colon (and has no `conference` option) which version do you have?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: The version of the one I'm using is the same as you quoted above.

Comment: something is different as it produces **.** not **:** and I checked the source there is no `:` in the class file. Can you show post your log file from the above test?  Note that whether it is a `.` or a `:` the layout is designed for a run-in header so it is a bit arbitrary how it comes out in this example where there is no text for it to run-in.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I added the log file's content to the question, if you kindly note.

Comment: you have a local file IEEEconf.cls that is not the same as the one on ctan (which does not have that ensure that any... text: http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEconf/IEEEconf.dtx